# Deklination (Nominativ oder Dativ) nach einem Doppelpunkt

Tags: grammar, dative, declension, apposition

Die Präposition *mit* verlangt den Dativ, aber wie ist es nach einem Doppelpunkt im Satz?

Sollen z. B. im Folgenden die Substantive *Sanierung* und *Neubau* im Nominativ oder Dativ geschrieben werden?

> Als Mitarbeiter im Büro habe ich mich vorher **mit** zwei Projekten beschäftigt: **die/der** Sanierung eines Pumpwerkes und **der/dem** Neubau eines Silos.

Comment: Ich sehe keinen Grund, nach Doppelpunkt abzuweichen.

Comment: d.h. Dativ? Das ist Ihre Antwort?

Comment: In diesem Fall, ja. In anderen Beispielen, was dort eben ohne Doppelpunkt benutzt würde.

Comment: Diese Formulierungen kann man häufig umschreiben mit ", nämlich" statt ":". Auch dort bleibt der Kasus.

Comment: Was meinen Sie ''nämlich'' statt '':''? Auf Deutsch bin ich leider nicht so erfahrene..

Comment: Simple Ersetzung: "... beschäftigt: der Sanierung...." oder eben "... beschäftigt, nämlich der Sanierung..." Und man kann den Doppelpunkt sogar einfach ersatzlos streichen: "... beschäftigt, der Sanierung..." Geht alles, Grammatik bleibt unverändert. Im letzten Fall fällt natürlich das "demonstrative" von Doppelpunkt oder "nämlich" weg.

Comment: Kann nämlich in einem Anschreiben geschrieben werden? Ist das Wort ''nämlich'' nicht umgangsprachlich oder informell? Danke

Comment: Ist zwar eine andere Frage, aber: warum nicht? Der Doppelpunkt ist übrigens nicht *falsch*, ich wollte nur seine "Neutralität" in Bezug auf die Grammatik zeigen. Im Anschreiben würde ich dagegen vorschlagen, die Schreibweise zu "Mitarbeiter" zu korrigieren und statt "beim Büro" den Genitiv in Betracht zu ziehen. Aber das wäre im chat besser aufgehoben...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dass die Präposition ***'mit'*** den Dativ regiert - damit ist es in diesem Fall noch nicht getan...

Da ***'beschäftigen'*** ein Verb ist, welches ein Präpositionalobjekt regiert (*'sich beschäftigen mit'*) wäre es nur *'korrekt'*, das wieder aufgenommene Objekt nach dem Doppelpunkt auch mit ***'mit'*** zu verwenden;

> - Als Mitarbeiter im Büro habe ich mich vorher **mit** zwei Projekten beschäftigt: mit ***der*** Sanierung eines Pumpwerkes und ***dem*** Neubau eines Silos.

Comment: »wäre es *nur* korrekt« nein, das wäre für mich zu hart. Ich finde, das *mit* kann auch weggelassen werden, schließlich wird es vorne schon genannt.

Comment: @Jan: Deshalb sagte ich auch ***'wäre'*** - grammatikalisch gesehen - der Alltagsgebrauch sagt natürlich etwas anderes... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sowohl *mit* alleine als auch *sich mit etwas beschäftigen* verlangen für das Beschäftigte den Dativ, soweit so gut. Und wie schon in Kommentaren und einer Antwort angedeutet, sollte demnach im Folgesatz auch der Dativ stehen.

Worin ich mit mramosch nicht übereinstimme: Meines Erachtens kann das *mit* nach dem Doppelpunkt, dass mramosch dort eingefügt hat auch entfallen. Ein *mit* steht schließlich vor dem Doppelpunkt; ein weiteres wäre Wiederholung. Völlig korrekt in meinen Augen wäre also:

> Als Mitarbeiter im Büro habe ich mich vorher mit zwei Projekten beschäftigt: **der** Sanierung eines Pumpwerkes und **dem** Neubau eines Silos.

(Was nicht heißen soll, dass die Variante mit *mit* falsch sei; ich halte das *mit* nur für überflüssig. Bevor es vom Pumpwerk weggepumpt wird, sollten wir es gleich einsparen.)

Comment: ***Wird*** auch in der Alltagssprache ohne *'mit'* verwendet - mit korrekt meinte ich grammatikalisch wirklich sauber. Und klingt auch runder mit *'mit'* meine ich zu hören. Ist hier wieder so eine ähnliche Problematik wie beim Zusammenziehen von Teilsätzen: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25570/grammatik-in-an-der-südgrenze-kontrolliert-die-bundespolizei-wurde-der-zugverk