# Grammatik in "An der Südgrenze kontrolliert die Bundespolizei, wurde der Zugverkehr ... eingestellt"

Tags: grammar, comma

Aus [Spiegel-Online](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/kommentar-fluechtlingskrise-merkel-muss-grenzkontrolle-zulassen-a-1052874.html):

> An der Südgrenze kontrolliert die Bundespolizei, wurde der Zugverkehr nach Österreich zeitweise eingestellt.

Ich verstehe, dass dieser Satz aus zwei Teilen besteht:

> An der Südgrenze kontrolliert die Bundespolizei. An der Südgrenze wurde der Zugverkehr nach Österreich zeitweise eingestellt.

Trotzdem möchte ich fragen: Ist der Satz grammatikalisch richtig? Es ist, als würde man schreiben

> An dem Wochenende gewann Dortmund, verlor Stuttgart.

Das fühlt sich nicht richtig an. Aber wenn es so wäre, dann wäre es völlig in Ordnung:

> Stuttgart gewann am Sonntag, verlor aber am Mittwoch.

Comment: Du solltest die zwei Fußballsätze noch mal als eigene Frage stellen. Das ist nämlich sehr interessant und zeigt feine Unterschiede.

Comment: Bite nicht vergessen: das ist eine Schlagzeile bzw. Überschrift einer Zeitung. Da gelten (auch und gerade im Enslichen) andere Regeln, bzw. nimmt man es mit der Gramamtik nicht immer ganz so genau.

Comment: @Ingmar Eine Schagzeile bzw. Überschrift ist es in diesem Fall nicht.

Comment: Es bleibt eine Zeitung. In Gebrauchstexten geht es vor allem um Verständlichkeit, und die ist in jedem Fall gegeben.

Comment: @Ingmar: Also ich höre/lese zwei Sätze und den zweiten Satzt eindeutig als Frage. Die einzige Möglichkeit unter der Annahme, dass die Grammatik stimmt... - Gebrauchstext hin oder her! - Wenn der Autor also eine Frage beabsichtigt hat, dann stimme ich mit dir überein, dass die Verständlichkeit gegeben ist - dann sollte er das Fragezeichen aber nicht vergessen ;-) Wenn keine Frage, dann schlichter unverständlicher Kauderwelsch. Nicht nur Muttersprachler die solche Rätsel vielleicht entziffern mögen lesen deutschsprachige Zeitungen...

Comment: @Ingmar: Welche Art Text ist denn kein Gebrauchstext? Gerade ein Text der brauchbar sein soll muss doch verständlich sein, und die Grammatik einzuhalten ist dafür mit entscheidend. Ich musste den Satz 2x lesen, was nahelegt, dass er unbrauchbar ist und unverständlich.

Comment: Literatur im weiteren Sinn zB, Lyrik, Dramatik ... Auch Belletristik als solche würde ich nicht mit diesem Attribut versehen. Wie auch immer: gerade bei Zeitungen und insbesondere bei Überschriften spielen eben auch andere Kriterien eine Rolle. Ich habe den Satz übrigens auf Anhieb verstanden, möchte daraus aber keine weiteren Schlüsse ziehen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alle drei Sätze sind grammatikalisch korrekt und machen Gebrauch von der [Zusammenziehung von Teilsätzen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Ordnung/Zusammenziehung.html). Diese Möglichkeit besteht dann, wenn nebengeordneten Teilsätze in einem (oder mehreren) Satzgliedern übereinstimmen. In beiden ersten Beispielen der Frage wird jeweils eine Adverbialbestimmung zusammengezogen, im dritten dann ein Subjekt (möglicherweise ein häufiger verwendetes und deshalb vertrauter wirkendes Muster). Komplett ausgeschrieben würde, wie Du schon richtig angenommen hast, der erste Satz lauten

> An der Südgrenze kontrolliert die Bundespolizei, an der Südgrenze wurde der Zugverkehr nach Österreich zeitweise eingestellt.

aber die Wiederholung von *an der Südgrenze* kann man weglassen.

Stilistisch finde ich den Satz aber eher fragwürdig, weil die beiden Teilsätze nicht in derselben Zeitform stehen, was es beim Lesen erschwert, die Wiederholung zu erkennen. Außerdem kann die Zusammenziehung nur schwach darüber hinwegtäuschen, dass der zweite Teilsatz redundant ist - jeder halbwegs in Geografie bewanderte Leser kann sich denken, wo die Grenze liegt, die die Züge nach Österreich überqueren; und letztlich könnte man ohne Zusammenziehung, aber mit exakt der gleichen Zeichenanzahl sehr viel klarer formulieren:

> An der Südgrenze kontrolliert die Bundespolizei, der Zugverkehr nach Österreich wurde zeitweise eingestellt.

(Oder auch ganz einfach in zwei Einzelsätzen.)

> An dem Wochenende gewann Dortmund, [an dem Wochenende] verlor Stuttgart.

Gleiches Prinzip. Hier würde (wie Carsten S. richtig angemerkt hat) ein 'und' zwischen den Teilsätzen für einen besseren Rhythmus sorgen - es sei denn, der Satz geht noch weiter:

> An dem Wochenende gewann Dortmund, verlor Stuttgart, und München spielte unentschieden.

Ein anderes Stilmittel, das ebenfalls auf einer Auslassung von Satzteilen beruht und das ich hier zunächst als Erklärung angenommen hatte, ist die  [Ellipse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(Linguistik)). Zum Unterschied zwischen Ellipse und Zusammenziehung habe ich eine eigene [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25590/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-ellipse-und-zusammenziehung) gestellt.

Comment: ***An dem Wochenende gewann Dortmund, [an dem Wochenende] verlor Stuttgart.***  (ist hier '*dem'* ein Artikel oder ein Demonstrativpronomen?) vs. ***An dem Wochenende gewann Dortmund, verlor Stuttgart, und München spielte unentschieden.*** (klingt noch immer holprig fürs Sprachgefühl / ausserdem ein Beistrich vor einem und ?!?). Die einzige akzeptable Lösung für mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir: ***An dem Wochenende gewann Dortmund, Stuttgart verlor und München spielte unentschieden.*** Wozu gibt es schliesslich die Regel des *'Verbes an der 2. Position'* im unabhängigen Teilsatz?

Comment: Kein einziger Beispielssatz in deinem Link klingt auch nur annähernd so un-deutsch wie deine als grammatikalisch-korrekt vorgeschlagenen Varianten... - ***An der Südgrenze kontrolliert die Bundespolizei, wurde der Zugverkehr nach Österreich zeitweise eingestellt.*** -> das hat ja nichts mit Deutsch zu tun - nicht mal ausgeschrieben in einer schlechten Zeitung. Zeig mir bitte ein seriöses Beispiel aus der Literatur, das sich so etwas traut...

Comment: @mramosch Der Beistrich vor _und_ war früher Pflicht und ist heute noch erlaubt, wenn _und_ zwei Hauptsätze miteinander verbindet - was hier (wenn wir uns den ausgelassenen Teil hinzudenken) der Fall ist. Das _dem_ stammt aus der Frage, mangels weiteren Kontextes verstehe ich es als Demonstrativpronomen. canoo.net nennt eine Reihe von Einschränkungen - das man Zusammenziehungen nicht verwenden darf, wenn dadurch ein leeres Vorfeld entsteht, ist nicht dabei. Wenn Du irgendwo eine solche Regel findest: her damit. Und ich sage ja auch nicht, dass man es machen sollte. Nur "verboten" ist es nicht.

Comment: Und deshalb gleich erlaubt oder korrekt nur weil es nirgendwo explizit verboten wurde ? Vor lauter Technik das Sprachgefühl komplett ausser Acht lassen ist auch nicht das Wahre. Ich glaube, nicht einmal Handke würde mich davon überzeugen und der ist Meister im Sätze verschachteln... - Aber ich sehe deinen Standpunkt. Danke!

Comment: @mramosch Das erste Beispiel bei canoo lässt sich leicht so erweitern, dass das Verb an 1. Stelle steht: "Das Buch liegt in der Bibliothek, _kann_ dort eingesehen werden, aber steht für die Ausleihe nicht zur Verfügung."

Comment: Genau deshalb steht ja das '*und*' und kein Beistrich (Komma) - ausserdem haben wir ein identisches Subjekt! Aber siehst du dort auch nur ein Beispiel mit einer temporalen Ergänzung die als *imaginärer* Platzhalter dienen kann um die Position des Verbes zu rechtfertigen? Ich nicht wirklich...

Answer (score 2):

Eindeutig inkorrekt! Wo ist das Objekt des Hauptsatzes/Nebensatzes? *'Kontrollieren'* ist ***'transitiv'***, auch wenn die Präpositional-Ergänzung das ein wenig verschleiern mag...

> - Die Polizei kontrolliert *'die Südseite'*
> - Die Polizei kontrolliert *'die Grenze'* an der Südseite
> - An der Südseite hat die Polizei *'die Kontrolle'* über
>     (meinetwegen ohne Akk.Ergänzung zur Präposition - im Sinne von *'über haben'*...)

Wenn das ein zweiter Hauptsatz ist:

> - ..., wurde der Zugverkehr nach Österreich zeitweise eingestellt.

ist er dann eine Frage mit dem Verb an erster Stelle?

Folgendes geht natürlich:

> Da an der Südseite die Polizei (die Grenze) kontrolliert, wurde der Zugverkehr nach Österreich zeitweise eingestellt,

Als Schlagzeile akzeptabel:

> An der Südgrenze kontrolliert die Bundespolizei - der Zugverkehr nach Österreich wurde zeitweise eingestellt.

Da wird so manches weggelassen um Platz oder Zeit zu sparen ;-)

Dein Gefühl ist genau richtig :-)

Comment: _kontrollieren_ kann auch ohne Objekt gebraucht werden, der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kontrollieren#Bedeutung2a) gibt selbst ein Beispiel dafür.

Comment: @Matthias: Nun, das einzige *'kleine'* Beispiel des Dudens (von mehr als zehn insgesamt), das kein Objekt verwendet ist ein Synonym für ***'Kontrolle ausüben'*** oder ***'die Kontrolle über haben'*** -> und das findest du auch in meiner Antwort explizit erwähnt... - Ausserdem funktioniert das auch nur wirklich gut wenn du ein Wort wie z.B. *'scharf'* dazusagst -> *'Hier kontrolliert die Bundespolizei scharf'* Klingt noch eher halbwegs deutsch als *'Hier kontrolliert die Bundespolizei'* - ***'WEN'*** oder ***'WAS'*** stellt sich da sofort die Frage... Objekt, Bitteschön !?! - Danke fürs DV ;-)

Comment: Da hast Du etwas zu schnell gelesen. [Kontrolle (sing.) ausüben](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kontrollieren#Bedeutung3) und [die Kontrolle (2) über etwas haben](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kontrollieren#Bedeutung4) sind zwei weitere Bedeutungen von _kontrollieren_. Ich habe verlinkt auf "Kontrolle**n** ausüben", was nicht dasselbe ist. Derjenige, der im Zug kontrolliert, geht durch die Gänge. Die Person, die die Kontrolle hat, sitzt vorne.

Comment: @Matthias: Nun, der Terrorist, der die Kontrolle über das Flugzeug hat sitzt ja (meistens) auch nicht vorne ;-) Und wo sitzt dann die Polizei an der Südgrenze? DUDEN: *'der Fahrer konnte ***'den Wagen'*** nicht mehr **kontrollieren**'* (einziges Beispiel zu *'Kontrolle über haben'*) - Wer hier WO geht, sitzt oder sonst was tut ist deine persönliche Interpretation die der Duden aber nicht belegt!  Ich hab's doch sehr genau gelesen... ;-)

Comment: Natürlich kann man sagen *'ich kontrolliere hier und du kontrollierst dort*' was aber nichts anderes heißt wie *'ich kontrolliere diesen Ort, du den anderen'*...

Comment: Du solltest Deinen letzten Kommentar nochmal auf Fehler kontrollieren. Und dann solltest Du kontrollieren, ob Du wirklich schon alle Bedeutungen von _kontrollieren_ verstanden hast. Die eine, die Du ziemlich penetrant ignorierst oder auf "Kontrolle haben" umzubiegen versuchst, ist nämlich gerade die, die für den Satz in der Frage [wichtig ist](http://polpix.sueddeutsche.com/bild/1.1096256.1355643645/860x860/rechtspopulisten-schengener-abkommen.jpg).

Comment: Ich meine durchaus nicht *'Kontrolle haben'* - nur *'kontrollieren'* wird nicht gleich wie z.B. *'patrouillieren'* verwendet! *'Ich gehe jetzt patrouillieren (eine Patrouille machen)'* klingt alleinstehend durchaus akzeptabel. Im Gegensatz *'Ich gehe jetzt kontrollieren'* zieht sicher die Frage ***wen/was*** nach sich. Hier müsste ich klar sagen ***'Ich mache jetzt eine Kontrolle'*** oder ***'Ich gehe jetzt eine Kontrolle machen'***,,, - Ohne Objekt klingt die OP anfangs auch eher nach Kontrolle haben, was dann aber mit dem zweiten Teilsatz (wenn er auch inkorrekt ist) ein wenig klarer wird...

Comment: @Matthias: Dein Link zu dem Foto mit der Polizei - welche Sprache ist das? Und was heißt hier *'pas'*? ***'passieren/vorbeifahren' - 'Passkontrolle' - 'nicht kontrolliert'*** ? Wenn es nämlich Dänisch oder Norwegisch ist, dann hast du hier Dein Objekt: Die Polizei kontrolliert den ***'Reisepass'***... - http://nyhederne.tv2.dk/article.php/id-26290148:d%25C3%25A5rlig-kontrol-med-falske-pas.html

Answer (score 0):

Das ist die sogenannte Bildzeitungs-Apposition, benannt nach dem Medium, das sie populär gemacht hat. Mittlerweile breitet sie sich auch in seriösen Medien aus. Zwei Hauptsätze, die mit derselben Wortgruppe beginnen, werden unter Weglassung der wiederholten Wortgruppe ohne Konjunktion aneinandergereiht, nur durch ein Komma getrennt. Grammatisch ist das nicht korrekt und eher dem Telegrammstil verwandt.

Comment: Hast Du dafür eine Quelle? Und eine Erklärung, wie die Benennung zustande kommt? Eine [Apposition nach der Definition bei canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html) kann ich hier jedenfalls nicht erkennen.

Comment: Und wenn es nicht wahr ist, ist es zumindest gut erfunden? Wo sind die Quellen für diese Anekdote? ;-)

Comment: Hm, scheint, ich muss diese Aussage zurückziehen. Mein alter Deutschlehrer hatte das immer so bezeichnet, aber eine Quelle finde ich jetzt tatsächlich nicht dafür.

Comment: Na das ist doch eine Quelle...;-) Auf wen sollen wir uns denn sonst berufen wenn nicht auf unsere Deutschlehrer...