# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Ellipse und Zusammenziehung?

Tags: style, rhetoric

Sowohl beim Stilmittel der [Ellipse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(Linguistik)) als auch in der im Deutschen möglichen [Zusammenziehung von Teilsätzen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Ordnung/Zusammenziehung.html) werden Satzteile weggelassen. Klar ist außerdem, dass es viele Ellipsen gibt, die keine Zusammenziehungen sind, wie z.B.

> Sonst noch was?

Aber sind Zusammenziehungen - manchmal, immer - Ellipsen?

Der Wikipedia-Artikel thematisiert das nicht, bringt aber eine Zusammenziehung als Beispiel für ein Ellipse:

> Karl fährt nach Italien, Wilhelm [fährt] an die Nordsee.

Auf der Suche nach weiteren Quellen bin ich erstaunlicherweise vor allem auf sehr alte Grammatiken gestoßen wie [diese hier](https://books.google.de/books?id=kNYLAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=ellipse%20zusammenziehung&source=bl&ots=d108JqEaBm&sig=PSTSsmckRe-SZLs7Rgg9_cpDHWA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAGoVChMIxc3H8tT5xwIVR40sCh2qigs1#v=onepage&q=ellipse%20zusammenziehung&f=false), in denen auf eine Unterscheidung der beiden Begriffe Wert gelegt wird.

Wie werden die beiden Phänomene heute gegeneinander abgegrenzt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohne aktuelle Literatur gewälzt zu haben, glaube ich, dass man den Fokus für die Unterscheidung zwischen **Ellipse** und **Zusammenziehung** oder **Verkürzung** heute etwas anders setzen würde, als Heyse dies vor über hundert Jahren getan hat.

Ein Satz oder eine Phrase mit **Ellipse** wird dadurch geprägt, dass darin zur prototypischen Formulierung, wie sie in der förmlichen Schriftsprache erwartet wird, bestimmte Satzteile fehlen, die durch grammatische Struktur und Rektion zu erwarten wären. Diese Teile stehen auch nicht im Kotext, sondern müssen aus Kontext oder sprachlichem Wissen ergänzt werden. In der mündlichen Kommunikation, in der eventuelle diesbezügliche Missverständnisse ggf. per Nachfrage geklärt werden können, ist die Ellipse ein völlig normales sprachliches Muster und als solche in oralen Grammatiken selbstverständlich vertreten. Im Geschriebenen kann sie hingegen leicht als schlechter Stil aufgefasst werden.

Im Gegensatz dazu sind **Zusammenziehung** oder **Verkürzung** in der Schrift gut akzeptiert, sogar ein beliebtes Stilmittel. Das, was bei ihnen ausgelassen wird, steht meistens schon kurz davor oder wird kurz danach genannt bzw. es ist ein durchgehender Topos des gesamten Textes, gehört also zum Kontext. Leser können sich nötigenfalls selbst orientieren, indem sie ein paar Worte, schlimmstenfalls Sätze zurückspringen, während Hörer sich bei solchen Formulierungen mitunter schon sehr konzentrieren müssen: In der Rede ist Redundanz hilfreich und üblich, im Geschriebenen wird sie weitgehend vermieden.

*Ellipse* klingt fachsprachlicher, weil es ein Fremdwort ist, und daher wird man häufig auch Zusammenziehungen und Verkürzungen damit bezeichnet finden.

Comment: "Kotext" ist kein Tipp-Fehler, sondern der Co-Text? Ansonsten schon mal sehr erhellend - danke! Ein, zwei Beispiele zur Veranschaulichung wären das Sahnehäubchen.

Comment: Ja, kein Tippfehler. Vielleicht komme ich heute Abend dazu, noch Beispiele zu ergänzen.

Answer (score 2):

In beiden Fällen wird etwas weggelassen, aber bei einer **Zusammenziehung** ist der Teil, der weggelassen wurde, an anderer Stelle vorhanden und kann von dort genommen werden um die Lücke zu füllen.

Dieser Satz enthält eine Zusammenziehung (die leere Klammer steht hier für etwas das fehlt):

> Karl **fährt** nach Italien, Wilhelm () an die Nordsee.

In diesem Beispiel wurden zwei Hauptsätze durch ein Komma zu einem Satz verbunden. Jedoch fehlt im zweiten Hauptsatz das Prädikat bzw. Verb:

> Wilhelm an die Nordsee. <sub>(Dieser Satz kein Verb!)</sub>

Das fehlende Verb steht aber im selben Satz, nur eben im vorangegangenen Hauptsatz:

> Karl **fährt** nach Italien. <sub>(Dieser Satz enthält ein Verb.)</sub>

Dadurch, dass man den Teil, der dem unvollständigen Hauptsatz fehlt, in Gedanken vom vollständigen Hauptsatz nimmt und an der Lücke einsetzt, entsteht dann der vollständige Satz:

> Karl **fährt** nach Italien, Wilhelm **fährt** an die Nordsee.

Das geht auch mit anderen Wortarten bzw. Satzteilen:

> Die Uni besitzt, aber der Professor verwendet das teure Messgerät.

Auch hier folgen zwei Hauptsätze aufeinander, wobei der erste unvollständig ist:

> Die Uni besitzt ().

Hier fehlt ein Akkusativobjekt, nämlich *das teure Messgerät*, welches im zweiten Hauptsatz enthalten ist. Zur Gänze ausgewalzt würde der Satz wie folgt lauten:

> Die Uni besitzt das teure Messgerät, aber der Professor verwendet das teure Messgerät.

Zu erwähnen ist, dass dies zwar grammatisch korrekt, aber kein schöner Stil ist, denn man kann das zweite Auftreten desselben Objekts durch dein Einsatz eines Pronomens vermeiden: »*Die Uni besitzt das teure Messgerät, aber der Professor verwendet **es***«

Noch ein Beispiel:

> Zu erwähnen ist, dass dies zwar grammatisch korrekt (), aber kein schöner Stil **ist**.
>   Zu erwähnen ist, dass dies zwar grammatisch korrekt **ist**, aber kein schöner Stil ().
>   Zu erwähnen ist, dass dies zwar grammatisch korrekt **ist**, aber kein schöner Stil **ist**.

---

Anders die Ellipse:

Der Wiener Opernball wird, nachdem die Debütantinnen und Debütanten getanzt haben, jedes Jahr mit diesen Worten eröffnet:

> Alles Walzer!

Auch hier fehlt etwas, nämlich das Prädikat bzw. Verb. Aber es gibt weder davor noch danach irgend einen Text, denn die gesamte Rede des Tanzmeisters besteht nur aus diesen beiden Worten. Es gibt also keinen in der Nähe stehenden ähnlichen Satz, von dem man sich etwas ausborgen könnte um die Lücke zu schließen. Und genau das unterscheidet die Zusammenziehung von der Ellipse: Das was den Satz vervollständigen könnte, ist nirgendwo vorhanden.

Bei der vorliegenden Ellipse ist klar, dass es sich um eine Aufforderung handelt, und da die Aufforderung einen Tanz betrifft, ist auch klar, dass das gemeint ist:

> Alles tanzt Walzer!

(Kleiner Exkurs: Mit »Alles« ist »alle Personen« gemeint, und »tanzt« ist ein Ersatz-Infinitiv für einen Imperativ, ähnlich wie in »Zwiebel *anrösten*« in einem Kochrezept)

Anders Beispiel:

> Wer da?

Auch hier fehlt das Verb (»ist«), und es ist nicht in der Umgebung der Frage vorhanden, sondern muss aus dem Kontext erraten werden.

Viele Ellipsen werden auch als Phrasen verwendet, bei denen man gar nicht erst versucht, sie in Gedanken zu vervollständigen:

> (*Ich wünsche dir einen*) **guten Morgen**.
>   (*Es*) **grüß**(e) (*dich*) **Gott**.
>   (*Zeigen Sie mir Ihren*) **Ausweis!**

Comment: D.h. die Wikipedia-Autoren haben mit "Karl fährt .." eher ein schlechtes Beispiel gewählt?